# Iphone: label text udates value but does not show in view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, singleton, label

I`m working on a part of code where a label text should change value after getting a new value from a singleton class. Seems simple enough, and after testing the value it actually changes aswell, but its not updated in the view. In the view it stays the same as before. I`ve tried the code both in -(void)viewDidLoad and `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`, but with the same result.. Any ideas?

Here are my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
//get the new status value
sharedBarCodeValue = [BarcodeValues sharedBarCodeValues];
if([[sharedBarCodeValue storeBarCodeValue] isEqualToString:@"123456"])
{
    [statusText setText:@"This is a new status text"];
}
//for testing, output status text
NSLog(@"status: %@", statusText.text);
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Edit: Oh, and I should mention that I´ve implemented a navigation controller, and the value should change when popping a 2. level view off the stack and going back to the root view.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your statusText outlet is properly connected to your IB object.

Comment: yes.. it is connected, I`ve tried typing statusText.text = @"test"; in viewdidload, and it changes the value in the view... so this is not the problem :(

Comment: could it have something to do with the navigation controller? maybe the view doesn`t refresh when changing from 2.level to root level in the stack?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you there.

Comment: hehe.. nvm.. i´ve even tried to create new labels programatically, but they don`t show.. something is very strange.....